# How to renew Google Play Music All Access from Android?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-music

I got the 30 days free trial for Google Play Music All Access, but I cancelled it. I'd like to renew it. How can I? I can't find a way. Here's an image:

[image: all access canceled]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVEP3l.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you canceled the trial and want to renew the TRIAL, I think you'll have to wait for another offer.

If you want to renew the actual service, go to Play Music, settings, Subscribe to All Access.